# dbapi для MySQL 5.0.82sp1

Tags: python, mysql

Имею машину с установленным MySQL сервером 5.0.82sp1. Подскажите есть ли db-api под данную версию? Использую python 3.8.7

Comment: *5.0.82sp1* Точно? уж больно версия странная.. что выводит `SELECT VERSION();`?

Comment: mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.0.82sp1 | 
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Вообще-то версии уже более 12 лет (2008 год!). При том что указанная версия питона достаточно свежая (декабрь 2020 г.). Вы правда думаете, что кто-то озаботился созданием/адаптацией API под версию сервера, давным-давно выведенную из эксплуатации? Не пора ли уже обновиться?